# How to update content of the app without publishing new version to Play Store

Tags: android, ios

So basically I have an app where I want to update it without pushing an update through the App Store. How would I go about doing this? What would I use, etc;

Preferably one that can be used for iOS and Android.

Comment: Nope different issue

Comment: Updating functionality on iOS requires that you submit the new version for review.  Attempting to avoid this can lead to your app being rejected and/or removed from the store for violating the review guidelines.

Comment: No not functionality just content.. text and images etc;

Comment: Content you can fetch from any storage service; Amazon S3, a web server, firebase...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to change content dynamically without updating the app, you need to use something like [Firebase Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/use-config-android). Read the link it will help you changing the values, content, and what you need without uploading code to Play Store.
It works for android and iOS as you need.